# Indent guideline highlighting doesn't work in Notepad++

Tags: notepad++

I used to use the indent guideline feature of Notepad++, but now I can't see the indent guideline. I don't know why. I'm sure that I didn't change any environment config options.

Where is there a menu I can use to turn the indent guideline on?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Just click the "Show Indent Guide" button in the toolbar.

Or, in the menu, select View > Show Symbol > Show Indent Guide.

Answer (score 1):

Here is Demo:

**Click Disabled "*show indent Guide*" result**
[image]

**Click Enabled "*show indent Guide*" result**
[image]

Please notice tags indentation and the difference between the two pictures, thanks!